# How to get custom dimensions of a custom data source via management API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Google Management API provides methods to get list of [custom data sources](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customDataSources) and [custom dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customDimensions).

However, I need to get the list of custom dimensions that belong to a custom data set, but can't find how. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatly it is not possible. The only data available about a custom data source is as follows:

```
{
  "id": string,
  "kind": "analytics#customDataSource",
  "selfLink": string,
  "accountId": string,
  "webPropertyId": string,
  "name": string,
  "description": string,
  "type": string,
  "uploadType": "analytics#uploads",
  "uploadType": "analytics#dailyUploads",
  "importBehavior": "OVERWRITE",
  "importBehavior": "SUMMATION",
  "profilesLinked": [
    string
  ],
  "created": datetime,
  "updated": datetime,
  "parentLink": {
    "type": "analytics#webproperty",
    "href": string
  },
  "childLink": {
    "type": "analytics#dailyUploads",
    "href": string
  },
  "childLink": {
    "type": "analytics#uploads",
    "href": string
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt for confirming my findings. Very strange it's not possible as dimensions is what make a data set.